# Can't put value of int into another activity

Tags: android, android-activity

Hi i need to put an value of first activity into second. In "original" i want to increment value by clicking on button,but now,i just created a variable for test that storing value 2. Now,i want to send this value to another activity,but i doing something wrong,because in second activity,my text view always showing 0. How i can solve this?

First class

Java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

int valueTV;
int test = 2;
Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this,showScore.class);
    intent.putExtra("",test);
    startActivity(intent);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            goToNextActivity();
        }
    });
}

public void incrementTV(View view) {
    valueTV = valueTV + 1;
    displayValue(valueTV);
}

private void displayValue(int number) {
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ID);
    textView.setText(String.valueOf(number));
}

public void goToNextActivity() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,showScore.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ID"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/test"
    android:textSize="100sp"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/add_btn"
    android:onClick="incrementTV"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ID"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/button"
    android:text="Button"
    android:onClick="goToNextActivity"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Second class

Java

```
public class showScore extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_score);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    int value = intent.getIntExtra("",0);
}

public void displayValue(int number){
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.random_id);
    textView.setText(String.valueOf(number));
}

}
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".showScore">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/random_id"
    android:text="@string/test_2"
    android:textSize="100sp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check below code

```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

int valueTV;
int test = 2;
Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            goToNextActivity();
        }
    });
}

public void incrementTV(View view) {
    valueTV = valueTV + 1;
    displayValue(valueTV);
}

private void displayValue(int number) {
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ID);
    textView.setText(String.valueOf(number));
}

public void goToNextActivity() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,showScore.class);
    intent.putExtra("",test);
    startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

in showmore class

```
    public class showScore extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_score);
    int number = 0;
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    int value = intent.getIntExtra("",number);
    displayValue(number)
}

public void displayValue(int number){
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.random_id);
    textView.setText(String.valueOf(number));
}

}
```

Comment: if this help to resolve your error then upvote ^ and mark as accept like https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/376420

Answer (score 0):

So i have now another problem. Like i said,i want to pass the data beetwen the activities,so i've make that there's 3 separate integeres should be send to the second activity,but i don't know why,the emulator keeps adding all of them. Basicly,i making an app,at case of my course - i need to create an app that keeping score,in my case,app would keep the score,number of fouls,and number of coreners during the football match. To set the data,we are clicking in special button (press score to increment score etc.) when we want to go to the second activity and see the detaileed statistics we should see like 3 goals,6 fouls,and like 2 corners for team "A" during the match,but when i clicking in buttons (suppose that is 1 time for goal,2 times for fouls,and 3 times for corner the app should be like 1 goal,2 fouls,3 corner's but it keep adding all of integeres,and it's like 6 goals,6 fouls,6 corners. What can be wrong?

Count activity (here program storage the value of integers)

```
public class CountActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public int team_a_score;
public int team_a_foul;
public int team_a_corner;

public int team_b_score;
public int team_b_foul;
public int team_b_corner;

private Button goToDetailedStats;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_count);

    goToDetailedStats = (Button) findViewById(R.id.go_to_stats);
    goToDetailedStats.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            openDetailedScore();
        }
    });

}

private void openDetailedScore() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,DeatiledScoreActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("",team_a_score);
    intent.putExtra("",team_a_foul);
    intent.putExtra("",team_a_corner);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void resetScore(View view) {
    team_a_score = 0;
    display_a_score(team_a_score);

    team_b_score = 0;
    display_b_score(team_b_score);
}

private void display_a_score (int a_score){
    TextView team_a_score_tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.team_a_score_tv);
    team_a_score_tv.setText(String.valueOf(a_score));
}
private void display_b_score (int b_score){
    TextView team_b_score_tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.team_b_score_tv);
    team_b_score_tv.setText(String.valueOf(b_score));
}

public void increment_a_score(View view) {
    team_a_score = team_a_score+1;
    display_a_score(team_a_score);
}

public void increment_a_foul(View view) {
    team_a_foul = team_a_foul+1;
}

public void increment_a_corner(View view) {
    team_a_corner = team_a_corner+1;
}

public void increment_b_score(View view) {
    team_b_score = team_b_score+1;
    display_b_score(team_b_score);
}

public void increment_b_foul(View view) {
    team_b_foul = team_b_foul+1;
}

public void increment_b_corner(View view) {
    team_b_corner = team_b_corner+1;
}
}
```

Detailed activity have to receive data that we send as intent from Counting activity.

```
public class DeatiledScoreActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_deatiled_score);

    int team_a_score_detail_int = 0;
    int team_a_foul_detail_int = 0;
    int team_a_corner_detail_int = 0;

    int team_b_score_detail_int = 0;
    int team_b_foul_detail_int = 0;
    int team_b_corner_detail_int = 0;

    Intent goal_intent = getIntent();
    int goal = goal_intent.getIntExtra("", team_a_score_detail_int);
    display_a_goal(goal);

    Intent foul_intent = getIntent();
    int foul = foul_intent.getIntExtra("", team_a_foul_detail_int);
    display_a_foul(foul);

    Intent corner_intent = getIntent();
    int corner = corner_intent.getIntExtra("", team_a_corner_detail_int);
    display_a_corner(corner);

}

public void display_a_goal(int score) {
    TextView a_score = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.team_a_goal_detail);
    a_score.setText(String.valueOf(score));
}

public void display_a_foul(int foul){
TextView a_foul = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.team_a_foul_detail);
    a_foul.setText(String.valueOf(foul));
}

public void display_a_corner(int corner){
    TextView a_corner = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.team_a_corner_detail);
    a_corner.setText(String.valueOf(corner));
}
}
```